# Importing Custom Proto Files other than google's

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node, grpc-js

Importing proto files from google such as Struct is pretty much straightforward as shown below:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package messages;

import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message UnaryRequest{
    google.protobuf.Struct data = 1;
}
```

I would like to replicate same flow with my team such that instead of
`import "google/protobuf/struct.proto"` we will have:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package messages;

import "myorg/protobuf/unary.proto"; //Notice difference here

message UnaryRequest{
    myorg.protobuf.UnaryData data = 1; //Notice difference here
}
```

Where `import "myorg/protobuf/unary.proto"` is expected to be retrieved from my orgs utility npm package which is reusable across internal microservices.

How can this be done?

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an automatic way for `protoc` to pull the npm package for you, but if you know where your orgs protos are gonna be after you pull them with `npm`, then you can include that path via `--proto_path <path>` option on `protoc`. The `import ...` statements will then resolve relative to all paths specified with that flag.

Not sure what build system you're using, but I bet you can automate this set up in most of them.

Comment: This is correct. `protoc` doesn't have a mechanism to pull imports. Imports must be locally installed. `protoc` doesn't pull Google's Well-Known Types, they're bundled with it and this is how it finds them. The only solution is to ensure that any imports are pulled before running `protoc` generally done by a build system.